# clip parent element with child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying some CSS tricks these days and I've got a problem.
for example:

```
<div class="parent" style="background-image: url("../x.jpg")">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="sec-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to make the background of `.parent` only show in the content-box of the child element, but failed. I know there are bunch of ways to clip `.child` and `.sec-child` to `.parent`;
But is it possible to clip`.parent` to `.child` and `sec-child`?

Comment: If this is css. Remove Jquery Tag

Comment: Also, and this is probably just a typo, but you're missing a closing tag on the `sec-child` div.

Comment: this jQ tag means I'm not so sure if it can be achieved with pure css. Jquery can be also used if neccessary. Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. It can be done with a little jquery:

```
$(".parent div").css("background-image",$(".parent").css("background-image"));
$(".parent").css("background-image","none")

$(".parent div").each(function(){

    var relativeY = $(this).parent().offset().top - $(this).offset().top;
    var relativeX = $(this).parent().offset().left - $(this).offset().left;
    console.log (relativeX+" "+relativeY)

    $(this).css("background-position",relativeX+"px "+relativeY+"px")

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hpvl/4r3056zv/21/

Comment: thanks! It gives me another way. However, i just found background-attachment combined with background-size very useful , little bit inflexible though